# stop words with mangled character encoding - help recover originals?

Tags: правопис

https://www.ranks.nl/stopwords/ukrainian has a short list of Ukrainian [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words), but some of them have been mis-OCRed or encoding-mangled or something:

> яко╞
>   в╡д
>   ╡
>   ╞х
>   ╙

Can anyone puzzle out what words these were supposed to be?

I regret I do not actually speak any Ukrainian.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest

> якої
>   від
>   і
>   їх
>   є

so there are the following pairs: `╞ ї`, `╡ і` and `╙ є`.

We can see that these letters don't appear in other stop words, even word *він* OCRed as *вІн*, so there is a problem with lowercase *і*.

Comment: This post is based on incomplete data set. It only guesses a possible answer, hence it can't be helpful. A new data in source data set may ruin this answer altogether. A really helpful answer would explain how `і ї є` (U+0456 U+0457 U+0454) underwent incorrect transformation between the codepages to become U+2561, U+255E, and U+2559, correspondingly.

Comment: @bytebuster Hmm.. I thought about this. Please, do answer this question with your very helpful information.

Comment: @bytebuster, I'd like to ask you to be patient and tolerant of the answers provided by other users. "It can't be helpful" — wrong, it certainly might be helpful if Yola's "suggest"ion is right. It might also be wrong. But it certainly might appear to be helpful. If you have a better solution for this question, I'd rather have you answer it by yourself, not saying to other users they're not helping. Suggesting changes or creating your own answer is always better than just criticizing.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Ukrainian text encoded in [KOI8-U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-U) or [KOI8-RU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-RU) (which contain the whole Ukrainian alphabet) and decoded in [KOI8-R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-R) (letters not used in Russian alphabet are replaced with frame-drawing characters).

Comment: Not exactly. That would be `яко╖ в╕д ╕ ╖х ╓` (and the question contains `яко╞ в╡д ╡ ╞х ╙`). But it's very close (maybe it was additionally mangled by some other transform or maybe it's not exactly KOI-U and KOI-R but some more rare encodings).